# ActionController::RoutingError No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, imagemagick, spree

On a fresh rails project, I'v installed Rails 3.2.11 with Ruby 1.9.3-p-194 I also installed spree version 1.3.1.

The steps that I took while installing:

```
    rails new mystore
    cd mystore
    spree install -A
    rails s
```

Everything is going without errors when I'm installing but when I open it in `http://localhost:3000/` product images are not loaded but the spree logo is loaded.

This is for the last image but i get the same for all product images:

```
Started GET "/spree/products/6/small/ror_jr_spaghetti.jpeg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-02 11:33:54 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/spree/products/6/small/ror_jr_spaghetti.jpeg"):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/vane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/vane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/vane/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/vane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)


Started GET "/assets/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-02 11:33:54 +0100
Served asset /favicon.ico - 304 Not Modified (28ms)
[2013-02-02 11:33:54] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

I checked my version of ImageMagic with `identify -version` and I got:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.2-2 2013-02-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: fontconfig freetype pango png ps x xml zlib
```

I also verifyed that the ImageMagick install is working properly with:

`/usr/local/bin/convert logo: logo.gif`

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong or it is another issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear out your database (`rake db:reset`) and then re-seed the data manually (`rake db:seed`) and see if that brings up any extra errors or works. I don't know why it wouldn't be showing images right off the bat.

Comment: `rake db:reset` performs well, but when I run `rake db:seed` it pops out this error: `loading fixture /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spree_core-1.3.1/db/default/spree/countries.yml
rake aborted!
SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: INSERT INTO "spree_countries" ("name", "iso3", "iso", "iso_name", "id", "numcode") VALUES ('Chad', 'TCD', 'TD', 'CHAD', 39, 148)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use this guide, actually: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

and you should be using the bundler. I didn't see anything about a spree install -a. I think you're supposed to do a bundle exec rails g spree:install, but I may be wrong.

*edit* Got it all working and submitted a pull request to you. I'm not sure what the issue was, exactly, but all I did to make it work was actually run the spree install again, and let it overwrite whatever it wrote before, and it looks like you were missing some more dependencies, plus I updated your spree to 1.3.2 cause 1.3.1 has an error. I hope this will get you somewhere.

Comment: I followed the guide and did it with `bundle exec rails g spree:install` but I get the same error. The `-A` is for accepting all the defaults.
Thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: I never heard of that before, in any case, did you check the routes? What about bundle exec rake routes and check that? It seems that route doesn't match against what you should have. Is this a default product that gets loaded in with a bundle exec rake db:seed or how is it put in?

Comment: I have this routes for the images `update_positions_admin_product_images    /admin/products/:product_id/images/update_positions(.:format)        spree/admin/images#update_positions... ` but this routes are for the admin panel. I don't have any other routes containing images. Do you think it is possible to be listed as a product property?

Comment: You'll have to check how you display the images. You must have the wrong code,then. i don't see anything under assets or even /images so there's definitely some kind of problem, unless these are stored inside of the database. If they're stored inside of the database instead of on the filesystem then there must be a route.

Comment: This is the only line i have in routes rb `mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'` should I have all 
[this lines](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/config/routes.rb)

Comment: Are you positive you didn't touch the codebase or any of the views? This just vanilla out of the box?

Comment: Yes, and I did a clean install and still the only line I had in routes.rb was `mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'`.

Comment: You also did bundle install and all gems installed okay? Hmm, seems maybe there is a problem with spree itself, can you put up your git project and let me have a look at it? I'm starting to wonder if maybe you're missing the sqllite libraries needed for your linux distro.

Comment: I did bundle install and all gems installed okay. This is my [git project](https://github.com/vaneandonov/spreestore). Thanks @Allen

Comment: Thanks to Allen the problem is solved.
With this line
`git pull https://github.com/HangingClowns/spreestore master` and
`bundle install` the images are there.

Comment: You can pull in the pull request, also.